# SUM values of multiple rows from result sets with identical column values SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, t-sql

From this query

```html
SELECT t1.type, t2.name, sum(t3.num) AS number, min(t1.price) AS price
FROM t1
JOIN t2
t1.soandso = t2.soandso
JOIN t3
ON t2.soandso = t3.soandso
GROUP BY t1.type, t2.name, t1.price
```

the result I'm getting is

```html
type   name   number  price
type1  name1  25      1
type1  name1  35      1
type1  name2  50      1
type2  name3  15      1
type2  name3  25      1
type2  name4  25      1
```

I want to be able to output

```
type    name    number    price
type1   name1   60        1
type1   name2   50        1
type2   name3   40        1
type2   name4   25        1
```

If it has something to do with subqueries, please include a brief explanation of what is happening where you place the subqueries. I'm not really understanding subqueries as much as I am understanding loops in pythons and javascript.

Comment: Remove price from GROUP BY.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
;with cte as (SELECT t1.type, t2.name, t3.num, t1.price
FROM t1
JOIN t2
t1.soandso = t2.soandso
JOIN t3
ON t2.soandso = t3.soandso)
SELECT type, name, sum(num) AS number, min(price) AS price 
from cte
GROUP BY type, name
```

Simplest way is this

Comment: what is the sum in the second select summing?

Comment: I did something similar to this except in the first select clause, i put sum(t3.num) as num. Then in the second select cause I did a sum(num) as number and group by type, name

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.type, t2.name, sum(t3.num) AS number, t1.price AS price 
FROM t1
JOIN t2 ON t1.soandso = t2.soandso
JOIN t3 ON t2.soandso = t3.soandso
GROUP BY t1.type, t2.name, t1.price
```